# Feature to move a question across Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

I have [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516866/move-files-between-document-libraries-in-the-same-site-collection-2) which although bountied on Stack Overflow never got any traction. Although I could re-post this on sharepoint.stackexchange.com and flag it for a moderator to merge it I was wondering - why *don't* we have a feature to easily move a question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do: we call them migrations. Regular users can vote to close a question as off-topic, and then select one of up to 4 other sites to migrate the question to. On Stack Overflow, that list is:

- Server Fault
- Super User
- TeX
- DBA

For sites like SharePoint that don't appear in the off-topic close list, or when you don't have enough reputation to vote to close a question yourself, if you flag the question for a moderator and tell them where it should go, they can take care of it.

In general though keep in mind that some sites—especially sites like SharePoint—overlap with Stack Overflow, and just because it might be on-topic there doesn't mean it's off-topic for Stack Overflow or that it should automatically be migrated. However, lack of answers (like in your case) is generally a good indicator that a migration is something to consider.

Comment: "*For sites like SharePoint that don't appear in the off-topic close list... you flag the question for a moderator and tell them where it should go*" Can you provide a step-by-step for doing this bit? There doesn't appear to be a way to say "this belongs on codereview" for example.

Comment: @DuncanJones Click the *flag* link below the question, select *it needs ♦ moderator attention*, select *other*, type in "This belongs on Code Review because [insert reason here]", press the *Flag Question* button.