# Why aren't all Stack Exchange sites available when flagging a question as off topic?

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/move-to-any-site)
>   [Should some communities have more than 4 migration targets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118685/should-some-communities-have-more-than-4-migration-targets)

It occurs to me, more often than not, that I want to flag a Stack Overflow question to move it to math.stackexchange, or other forums, but this option is not available.

If there were at least a comment or reason textbox in the flag form.

Comment: There are several dupes for this question. Basic idea is that in general users active on one site have a very poor idea of what is on-topic for another site, resulting in a lot of rejected migrations. (P.s. they are not forums, but Q&A-s. Very important difference)

Comment: And you could always flag a certain question with a custom flag reason, indicating that you think a certain site within the network would be a good migration targets. Mods could migrate it there if appropriate and accepted by the target site.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142121/feature-to-move-a-question-across-stack-exchange-sites - "why *don't* we have a feature to easily move a question?"

Comment: see related [How do I migrate a question to a site which is not listed in close window?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140372/173001)